# Adding a button to a combobox in wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Pretty much I have an Editable Combobox and I want to add a button to the right of the drop down button which clears the selected item. So...

|TextBox |X|v|

I was thinking something like...

```
<Style...>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">...Add button here...</Style>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that your proposed approach will work. As soon as you set the `Template` property in the style, you will also have to redefine its visual representation. You could, however, define an adjusted `ControlTemplate` for a `TextBox` (as you suggested) in the `Resources` section of the `ComboBox` (not within its Template!).

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <!-- define template for TextBox with an additional "clear" button -->
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

But then you still have the problem *how to handle the click on this button*...

A **clean solution** would be to sub-class `ComboBox` and provide an `ICommand` which clears the current selection. Then you would override the `ComboBox`'s `ControlTemplate`, add a "clear" button besides the drop down button and bind that button to the new `ICommand`. This definitely is quite some work, but in the end you have a clean solution which you can easily extend later on.

Comment: Good answer. Re-templating for this sort of experience is pretty standard and the way to do it... and through extra visuals in the template with code-behind event bindings, commands, or new sub-classes, they all get you there.