# WPF Combobox with clear button

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, custom-controls

I am trying to create a WPF ComboBox control which contains a clear button when something is selected. The control should have two states: if something is selected the control looks like a label with a clear button. If nothing is select then a normal ComboBox is display. The two states are showing  in the picture below.

[image]

Researching my problem I came across the following SO questions which are very similar to mine:

[Adding a button to a combobox in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807481/adding-a-button-to-a-combobox-in-wpf)

[How to subclass a WPF ComboBox to add an extra button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515125/how-to-subclass-a-wpf-combobox-to-add-an-extra-button)

Both suggest subclassing the ComboBox providing a modified template with the extra button. But this is where I am a tad confused. The answer by John Bowen to the second linked question indicates that I should copy the ComboBox's default template; modifying it to include a button getting the template from Blend. Not being proficient with blend I found the template on MSDN here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.85).aspx

My problem is I am not quite sure what I should change. Looking at the Default template I think I need to do something along the lines of:

- Create a new 'IsSelected' property which I can hook triggers to.
- Add a control template for a Clear Button with trigger attached to IsSelected which hides the button.
- Attached a IsSelected Trigger to the ComboBoxToggleButton control template to hide it upon selection.
- Somehow re-size the `PART_EditableTextBox` textbox in the ComboBox Template when IsSelected is true.

Does this seem right and any pointers on how I do it or other suggestions if I am barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: you could use a Converter (google it) to set the Visibility of two controls based on the selection. I don't have the time to give an example so I won't post it as an answer

Comment: You do need to build a new control template, but you need to create a new `VisualState` that is turned on when something is selected. If you leverage the `VisualState` then when the clear button sets the `SelectedValue` to `null` it will respond properly.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you will accept a simpler solution - just place a TextBlock with a Button above your ComboBox?

The xaml will look like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" x:Name="cbox"/>
    <Grid Background="Gray" Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cbox, Converter={StaticResource NullItem2Visibility}}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cbox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Button Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="ClearItem"/>
    <Grid>
</Grid>
```

Codebehind will have method ClearItem:

```
public void ClearItem(object sender, EventArgs e){
    cbox.SelectedItem=null;
}
```

And the converter to show and hide textblock and a button:

```
class NullItem2Visibility:IValueConverter{
    public object Convert(object value, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo i){
        return value == null ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(...){...}
}
```

Comment: This is what I was suggesting with my comment. I am sure there are other ways to do it, but this one works well.